# How to collapse regions in selected code only?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

How do I collapse all **selected** code?

I don't want to collapse all code such as by Ctrl+M Ctrl+O.

I want to select a certain area and then collapse everything in that selection at once.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Ctrl+M`, `Ctrl+M` shortcut will *toggle* the collapsed state of the selected code.  If the selection is mixed (i.e. some collapsed, some expanded), the it will collapse the expanded parts of the selection. Doing it a second time will then go the other way, expanding the entire selection.

Answer (score 2):

There is a Hide Selection command (<kbd>Ctrl+M</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+H</kbd>) that will create a new outlining region spanning the exact selection and collapse it.

The region can be removed with the Stop Hiding Current command (<kbd>Ctrl+M</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+U</kbd>).

As @madreflection mentioned, there is also the Toggle Outlining command (<kbd>Ctrl+M</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+M</kbd>), which toggles any outlining regions within the selection.